# Copy range from column A and write to column B

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range in column A and I want to write for each element of range A something in Cell B. I am using this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range("A:A" & LastRow).Select

    For Each Cell In rng2
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=isOK"
    Next Cell
```

What I want to write in column B. The last cell in A is 1887:

[image]

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your code, give it a try :

```
Dim Cell as Range, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each Cell In rng2
    If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "isOK"
Next Cell
```

Comment: This gives me an debug error for  If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then...it says type mismatch

Comment: from picture you attached, it looks like in column A are string values, like "331 HK", it won't work with numbers.

Comment: I edited my answer, I guess you want to have value "isOK" in column B, and it's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Set rng2 = Range("A:A" & LastRow).Select

this should be Set rng2 = Range("A**1**:A" & LastRow)

and your offset is the cell underneath, should be (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using Select as much as you can, it is a source of trouble. In this code, you dont need to use it.
I suppose that isOK is a user-defined function (UDF):

```
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    For Each Cell In rng2
        If not IsEmtpy(Cell) Then Cell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=isOK()"
    Next Cell
```

Comment: This gives me an debug error for  If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then...it says type mismatch

Comment: @Nant ok plz try the edited code, using IsEmpty(Cell). As I said in the answer, i supposed that isOK() is a UDF defined in some code module. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Try that better with normal excel formulas:

```
=if(lookup(A1;C1:Z20)=0;"isOK";"notOK")
```

copy that into every cell in column B and you will get your expected result ;)